# How can I make my DB connection UTF8 enabled

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB which I've filled using PHPMyAdmin with German paragraphs, and when I try to retrieve data from DB I only get ?? .. so how can I make sure that the connection to DB is UTF8 enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

"Sets the default character set for the current connection."

[mysql_client_encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-client-encoding.php)

"Retrieves the character_set variable from MySQL."

```
<?php
$link    = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($link);

echo "The current character set is: $charset\n";
?>
```